# Des formats des questions formelles et informelles

Tags: grammaire, questions, interrogative

Il y a plusieurs façons de poser une question en français. On peut utiliser « est-ce que », mettre le verbe devant le pronom (eg, « vas-tu au resto ce soir ? »), ou on peut seulement utiliser l'intonation pour indiquer une question.

Je suis un peu confuse :

1. Pour parler avec mes amis, quel format de question devrais-je utiliser ?
2. Et pour des situations formelles ?
3. En français écrit, est-ce qu'il est nécessaire d'utiliser « est-ce que » ou de mettre le verbe devant le pronom ? Ou est-il suffisant de mettre seulement un « ? » à la fin de la phrase ?

Comment: C'est manifique ! Merci :)

Comment: La situation est compliquée et dépend de la structure syntaxique de la phrase "subjacente" (quel type de sujet, présence de quels compléments) ainsi que de la catégorie générale de l'interrogation (totale ou partielle) et du registre. Une autre référence qui pourrait vous aider: http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/questions.shtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

À l'oral, la version « est-ce que » est passe-partout excepté peut-être dans des situations très formelles. Dans la vie de tous les jours, mettre le verbe avant le pronom vous vaudra des réactions étonnées ; presque personne ne parle comme ça. Je n'imaginerais pas le faire sauf, par exemple, pour un entretien d'embauche.

Changer seulement l'intonation est plutôt réservé aux amis et en général aux gens qu'on tutoie. Mais « est-ce que » est aussi couramment utilisé dans cette situation.

À l'écrit, mettre le verbe avant le pronom est la manière normale. La seule exception habituelle qui me vient à l'esprit concerne les dialogues, où on peut évidemment utiliser le registre oral.

Comment: N'est-il pas courant d'avoir le verbe avant le pronom à l'oral, lorsqu'on utilise être/avoir seulement? E.g. quelle heure est-il? As-tu mangé? L'absence d'inversion serait entre amis, ou de la part d'un enfant.

Comment: @EricPlaton Je suis plutôt de l'avis de Jhyn: à l'oral, l'inversion me paraît très très formelle, surtout accompagnée d'un tutoiement, mais même en vouvoyant. Je me vois plus facilement dire "Vous avez mangé ?" que "Avez-vous mangé ?", même à mon futur patron en entretien d'embauche (à l'oral, j'entends).

Comment: Quelle forme serait meilleure ?: "Quand as-tu mangé ?" ou "Quand est-ce que tu as mangé ?"

Answer (score 1):

Je reprends la structure de la question pour ma réponse :

1) pour parler à des amis tu peux simplement changer l'intonation :

> Tu habites en Belgique ?

2) pour une situation formelle on a une inversion verbe-sujet + l'utilisation de la 2e personnes du pluriel en général, la forme polie :

> Habitez-vous en Belgique ?

3) à l'écrit on utilisera rarement le point 1) propre à l'oration. On préfera le cas 2) pour les écrits formels ou le standard avec *est-ce que* + sujet-verbe :

> Est-ce que tu habites en Belgique ?

à noter que dans le point 2) on peut garder le sujet devant et avoir une inversion sujet-verbe dont le sujet est repris via un pronom (ici *il* pour *François*) :

> François habite-t-il en Belgique ?

Comment: Le dérnier example que vous avez donné est interessant - je n'avais jamais vu cette structure où on met le sujet et après on ajoute une combination de pronom-verbe. Merci :)