# Comment dit-on « How did you learn French? »

Tags: questions

Est-ce qu'il est correct de dire :

> Comment est-ce que vous avez appris le français ?

Comment: C'est tout à fait correct. On pourrait aussi dire « Comment avez-vous appris le français ? ». Voir [cette question et sa réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11097/des-formats-des-questions-formelles-et-informelles) sur les façons de poser une question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, il est <strike>très</strike> correct de dire : « Comment est-ce que vous avez appris le français ? »

Une façon plus officielle, ou formelle de dire la même phrase, serait : « Comment avez-vous appris le français ? »