# Can "ce que", "ce qui", and "ça" be used to refer to things previously mentioned

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, démonstratifs

Can the words "ce que", "ce qui" and "ça" be used to refer to something previously mentioned?

Like in the sentence

> Nous allons parler de ce que
>   "Let's talk about *that*"

This

> En ce qu'un seconde
>   "In *that* one second"

And

> Je suis désole si c'était stupide
>   "I am sorry if that (what speaker previously said) was stupid

Also, an out of topic question: 
Do you invert the subject and verb when you use Pourquoi at the start of a sentence?

Comment: You seem to have 2 different questions. One about ce/ce qui/ce que, and the one at the end about word order in a pourquoi question. The SE format is one question at a time and that helps getting good answers. Since you're new to SE a tour of the Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) might be a good idea. Welcome to FL.

Comment: Sorry for posting, I feel that I sort of spam when I ask too much haha.

Comment: Don't worry. There have already been questions about word order in questions. [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11097/des-formats-des-questions-formelles-et-informelles) for instance. If you feel a question has already been asked but it's in French and your French isn't (yet) just up to it, plenty of people here can translate.

Comment: Would this answer your question? http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11649/358

Comment: Please give more context. Both sentence fragments could have different meanings and constructions depending on the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @Gilles I edited it

Comment: @chaplinmyflabbydog You didn't give more context. You examples are too short to understand what you want to mean...

Comment: Context or not, these examples are grammatically incorrect and mean nothing. Nous allons parler de ce que -> nous allons parler de cela ; en ce qu'une seconde -> en cette seconde. The third example is correct. *Que* in *ce que* is the relative pronoun, so you need a relative proposition. *Ce que* is closer in meaning to *what* than to *that* : *ce que je disais* means *what I was saying* ; it can't be used alone. *Cela*, however, can, and it does mean *that*.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the words"ce que/ce qui/ça" be used to refer to something previously mentioned?

Yes, but not as illustrated in your examples. Let's fix them.

> Nous allons parler de ce que.

`que` here is referring to something coming after, so the sentence feels like it has been truncated. A correct one would be:

*Nous allons parler de **ce qu'il s'est passé**.* (Let's talk about *what happened*.)

A similar example would be the colloquial:

*Pour faire valoir **ce que de droit**.* (For all due intents and purposes.)

You probably intended to say something like:

*Nous allons **en** parler.* (We will talk *about it*.)
*Nous allons parler **de ça**.* (We will talk *about that*.)

> En ce qu'un seconde "In that one second"

Again, the example feels truncated or a part is missing. I interpret the meaning more like "In what would have taken one second."

You can say instead:

*En **cette** seconde.* (*During that second*, or *From this instant*, depending on context.)

> Je suis désole si c'était stupide.

Ironically, this one is correct, except for the missing accent at *désolé*.