# "Vous en voulez ?" for uncountable noun

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

"I have some milk. Do you want some?"

> J'ai du lait. Vous en voulez ?

Is it correct to use "Vous en voulez ?" without any pronoun following it? If the noun were countable, we would need a pronoun:

> J'ai des bouteilles de lait. Vous en voulez **une** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Vous en voulez ?*** is correct in the first sentence. If you want to state something after the verb, that can be *vous en voulez **un peu** ?*.

In the second sentence, ***une*** is correct but not mandatory because it limits the choice (like *un peu* in the previous case). You would say ***vous en voulez ?*** when you want to leave the number of bottles unspecified.

---

Off topic but note that the level of language will change the way the question would be asked:

> *En voulez-vous ? En veux-tu ?* (formal, taught at school but seldom used)
>
> *Est-ce que vous en voulez ?* Est-ce que tu en veux ? (common)
>
> *Vous en voulez ? Tu en veux ?* (common, slightly colloquial)
>
> *T'en veux ?* (definitely colloquial)

Comment: Why "En voulez-vous?" is Off topic? And what makes you assert that it is "seldom used"?

Comment: @sapienz *En voulez-vous* is not specifically off topic, the whole part about the language levels in my reply is off topic. The reason is it doesn't answer what is asked by the OP, i.e. the pronoun presence.

Comment: @sapienz and what makes me assert it is seldom used is the well known fact inversion in particular and formal French in general are seldom used.

Comment: I disagree with your analysis. In formal french, "En voulez vous?" is used as well "Vous en voulez?"

Comment: @sapienz *Vous en voulez ?* is obviously not formal French. [It is colloquial French.](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11097/des-formats-des-questions-formelles-et-informelles) Formal French does not break grammar rules.

Answer (score 0):

> En voulez vous?

or

> En voulez vous une?

is correct as well.